# Implementation of Mean Absolute Scaled Error in tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, forecasting

I implemented the Mean Absolute Scaled Error (MASE), which I want to use in a Keras model as a metric.

I don't know if the slicing is correct for tensors, in the *sust* expression.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_scaled_error

```
def mase(y_true, y_pred):

    sust = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_true[:,1:] - y_true[:,:-1]))
    diff = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(y_pred - y_true))

    return diff/sust
```

Comment: What does "correct" mean to you? How should it look? One way to do this is to say `print(sust)` within your `mase` function, show what it outputs and explain how this is different to what you expected =)

Comment: This is a problematic implementation, because this assumes your timeseries is not shuffled. This only works if y_true is in chronological order, which it often is not due to shuffling or larger horizons of prediction. The proper way to do this would be to build a naive model and take the average error of that as a norm for your own model.